# Uniform continuity and integration

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ integrable in $[a,∞)$ and $g\left( x \right) =\int _{ a }^{ x }{ fd\mu  } $.

Show that $g$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,∞)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$.  Let $E_n=\{x \in [a,\infty): |f(x)| \ge n\}$. Then $$\lim_n\int_{E_n}|f|d\mu =0$$ implies that there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $\int_{E_n}|f|d\mu \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  For any $x \gt y \in [a,\infty)$ with $|x-y| \lt \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2k}$, we have 
$$|g(x)-g(y)| \le \int_y^x |f|d\mu=\int_{[y,x] \cap E_k}|f| d\mu+\int_{[y,x] \cap E_k^c}|f| d\mu \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$